# df reported size/used/available discrepancy

Tags: linux, df

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-Backups  425G  377G   27G  94% /Backups
```

- Size = 425G
- Used = 377G
- Available = 27G
- Used + Available = 404G != 425G

Why is used+available different from total size? This is not happening in any other 
server.

I've tried remounting and rebooting the system.

`du` shows that the "Used" space in the `/Backups` directory from the `df` 
command is correct.

Details:

- Slackware 13.37.0
- Linux 2.6.37.6-smp #1 SMP Sat Apr 9 14:01:14 CDT 2011 i686 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5530 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
- HP DL360 G6

Comment: Hello BiFo. This is a programming Q&A site, not a general support forum. Please use a search engine, this type of question is asked (and answered) a lot.

Comment: Possibly a portion of the filesystem capacity was automatically reserved for the superuser?  Or you have some cleverly hidden something on there, or a broken filesystem.

Comment: Try bind mounting your file system and see if there are any files hidden behind your mount points.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/79981/df-h-shows-incorrect-free-space (and tons of other similar discussions).

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely due to reserved space for the super-user on an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem, plus a small rounding error when converting blocks to gigabyte sizes. See this [similar discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1636659).